# Create dictionary from list of tuples using second element

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of lists of tuples like this:

`new = [[('name', 'n1')], [('value', 'v1')], [('name', 'n2')], [('value', 'v2')], [('name', 'n3')], [('value', 'v3')]]`

I want to map the first `'name'` tuple to the first `'value'` tuple, second to second, etc. What I have been doing is this:

```
res = dict(zip(new[0],new[1]))
```

which gives me `{('name', 'n1'):('value', 'v1'), ('name', 'n2'):('value', 'v2'), ('name', 'n3'):('value':'v3')}`. This is close, but I really just want this: `{'n1':'v1', 'n2':'v2', 'n3':'v3'}`.
I just want the second element from the tuple. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
print(dict((x[0][1], y[0][1]) for x, y in zip(new[::2], new[1::2])))
```

---

```
{'n1': 'v1', 'n2': 'v2', 'n3': 'v3'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
res= {new[2*i][0][1]:new[2*i+1][0][1] for i in range(len(new)//2)}

>>> res
{'n1': 'v1', 'n2': 'v2', 'n3': 'v3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new = [[('name', 'n1')], [('value', 'v1')], [('name', 'n2')], [('value', 'v2')], [('name', 'n3')], [('value', 'v3')]]
output = {}
while new:
    key = new.pop(0)
    value = new.pop(0)
    output[key[0][1]] = value[0][1]

print(output) 
# output: {'n1': 'v1', 'n2': 'v2', 'n3': 'v3'}
```